# JS snippet plugin for sublime that'd inlude w3schools functions

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, code-snippets

I searched everywhere for a sublime text plugin that'd incorporate many of the functions on W3Schools so I don't have to go back and forth.
For example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Any idea what is a good plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try Webstorm http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/ ))

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a lot. Infact, a quick Google search brings up something promising: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/JavaScript%20%26%20NodeJS%20Snippets

Second, let's not refer to those "w3schools functions" as such, for they are standardized functions of ECMAScript available on several JavaScript implementations, and are in no way associated with w3schools.